# A 'cd ..' Alternative to Quickly Moving to Ancestor Directories in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

I use a Windows command prompt for primary navigation on my Window 7 development machine, and my daily process requires me to get from one location to another in the directory structure quite frequently.  I notice that I use 'cd ..' frequently to move to ancestor directories in the directory structure.  Is there any solution to reducing the typing cost of multiple sequential 'cd ..' commands?  For instance, if I could type a command that would move me up x ancestors up into the directory structure, then I wouldn't need to type 'cd ..' x times.
The primary goal is to get around quicker and more efficiently, so other answers that solve the general goal are also appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The old MS-DOS `command.com` would let you type `cd ...` to go up two levels, `cd ....` to go up three levels, and so on. For some reason they didn't implement it in `cmd.exe`. It was rather handy; I still try to do it every now and again just out of some sort of sub-conscious habit.

Comment: IIRC that wasn't a feature of command.com but 4DOS by JP Software, which was a command.com replacement/enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a times=%1 2>NUL
IF NOT DEFINED times SET /a times=1
IF %times%==0 (CD "%~1") else (FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,%times%) DO CD ..)
GOTO :EOF
```

How about this - save it on your `path` and call it say `cdx.bat`

```
cdx n
```

with n numeric should rise n levels.
Otherwise, should go to directory nominated as %1

Yes - I'm aware that the evaluation isn't complete or bulletproof. That's an exercise for those who may be interested...

Comment: I like the idea of using one command and an integer parameter rather, seems code wasteful to create a separate command for each x.

Answer (score 2):

Use `..\` like so:

```
cd \
cd "Program Files"
cd "Common Files
cd ..\..\..\
cd
> C:\
```

You can also use `doskey` to create aliases, so rather than constantly typing iterations o `..\` you can use `doskey` like so:

```
C:\Users\Foobar\>doskey u2=..\..\
C:\Users\Foobar\>doskey u3=..\..\..\
C:\Users\Foobar\>u2
C:\>
```

Comment: How do I make the doskey persist between command prompt processes?

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file called `c.bat` in `c:\windows` or somewhere else on the PATH

```
@echo off
cd ..
```

It's a start.

Comment: Typing c sequentially to execute the batch file x times to move x levels into the ancestor tree saves me a few key strokes, thank you for the response, but Magoo's answer will save me even more.