# CMD change directory to parent directory n times

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, parent

I don't know very much about `cmd` so I wonder if there is a shortcut to go n levels up with something like, for example:

```
cd ..^3
```

instead of:

```
cd ../../..
```

[Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20440350/2633637)

Comment: You can use `CD /D` to go wherever you want specifically but if you just want an arbitrary up 3 levels, the `../../..` method is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when typing at the cmd prompt:

```
cd .. and enter
uparrow and enter
uparrow and enter
```

In a batch file:

```
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
```

or this:

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,3) do cd ..
```

Comment: Nice, but... batch-file version?

Comment: :) first option is obvious, but the second is very interesting to my purpose. Then the only thing to change if you want to go n levels up is 3-->n. Right?

Comment: Yes.  The loop counter starts at 1 and increments by 1 until it gets to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a useful way of doing this. And I'll delete it if it gets converted again to a comment.

I'd suggest [response to similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20438795/2128947)which was posted a little over a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Define an alias for your cd operation

```
doskey ..=(if "$1"=="" ( @cd ..\ ) else (for /l %x in (1 1 $1) do @cd ..\))
```

Then, use

```
`.. 1` or `..` for `cd ..`  
`.. 2` for `cd ..\..` 
etc.
```

You can save your macros to a file with `doskey /macros > dosKeyMacros.txt` , and restore them with `doskey /macrofile=dosKeyMacros.txt`.

To automatically load the list on command open, you will need to change your command "[Autorun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439%28WS.10%29.aspx)" registry